# How to mock Google Pubsub requests in integration tests (node)?

Tags: node.js, testing, integration-testing, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm writing integration tests for an API in NodeJs that publishes to Google PubSub topics. I don't want to really trigger those external messages in testing environment, so I need some kind of mock.

Since it's an integration test, I think the best approach would be to intercept external network calls to the pubsub service, returning a mocked response.

I tried using [nock](https://github.com/nock/nock) for this, but it didn't work. I think maybe because google's lib implementation is over gRPC / http2 (?)

Is there any solution to this or a better approach? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @PedroBarros, Are you writing integration tests to Amazon API?

Comment: Hi @PrajnaRaiT, no, I'm writing to a node application that consumes GCP's PubSub